# Define custom field with get_option() in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, yoast

I have some a custom settings page to define some global variables. So right now I can print my variable with:

```
echo get_option('dealcity');
```

But I need to be able to use the result in my page titles with Yoast, however using Yoasts custom field code %%cf_dealcity%% doesn't work. I guess because dealcity is an option setting rather than a custom field. So I think I need to define the option as a custom field. I tried using the following and then trying %%cf_dealercity%% but that didn't work:

```
function save_your_fields_meta( $post_id ) {   
$dealercity = get_option('dealcity');
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_your_fields_meta' );
```

Comment: You can check if it is an option by looking at the WP_Options table in the DB. If it is in there, get_option() should work. Also, your code example is not actually doing anything. You are saving the option but doing nothing within on save. Is this all the code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet you might just be looking for updating custom fields on the `save_post` hook? In your example nothing will happen because you don't do anything with `$dealcity` after you define it, and you need to save it with [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/):

```
function chrislovessushi_fields_meta( $post_id ){   
    if( $dealcity = get_option( 'dealcity' ) ){
        // Make sure $dealcity exists, then update the post meta
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'dealcity', $dealcity );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'chrislovessushi_fields_meta' );
```

Also for future brain candy, you can modify page titles with some simple filters, like [`the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) for page titles and/or [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) for the `<title>` tag:

```
function chrislovessushi_title_filter( $title, $id = null ) {
    if( is_page() ){
        // Add `dealcity` value before title if this is a page
        $title = get_option('dealcity').' '.$title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'chrislovessushi_title_filter', 10, 2 );
```